# Laravel 5:webpack build angular js not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

Here is my webpack script to build angularjs route file and angular core file

```
mix.js([
    'node_modules/angular/angular.min.js',
    'node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js'
],'public/js/angular.js');
```

However the build is success and output file is present in `js` folder,but when i include this in my main page angular routing and angular related scripts are not working no error shown in console.

But when i include the CDN of these angular-route and min everything works fine

Comment: Did you try with the unminified files instead .min?

Comment: Nop let me try with it

Comment: is the path correct?

Comment: @MrNew yes paths are correct if not the build failed

Comment: @Polak tried with unminfied same error